# Nav links wont work

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

My nav links will only toggle the nav menu itself. I had it working at the beginning and for most of the project, but somewhere along building a more dynamic footer this just stopped working and cant seem to find where the problem is. I thought it would have something to do with its index or possibly an overlow issue

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#nav-mobile ul').hide();
  $('#socialbtns').removeClass("socialbtns");
  $('#ig').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-instagram");
  $('#twitter').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-twitter");
  $('#linkin').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-linkedin");
  $('#trademark').removeClass("footer3");
  $('#nav-mobile').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#nav-mobile ul').slideToggle();
  });
  resize();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    resize();
    if(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 999px)").matches){
      $(' <span> Instagram </span>').appendTo("#ig");
      $$(' <span> Twitter </span>').appendTo("#twitter");
      $('<span> LinkedIn </span>').appendTo("#linkin");
      $('#trademark').addClass("footer3");
    }
    });
});


function resize(){
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1000px)").matches) {
    $('#nav-mobile').hide();
    $('#socialbtns').addClass("socialbtns");
    $('#ig').addClass("fa fa-md fa-instagram");
    $('#twitter').addClass("fa fa-md fa-twitter");
    $('#linkin').addClass("fa fa-md fa-linkedin");
    $('span').remove();
    $('#trademark').removeClass("footer3");
  }
  else {
    $('#nav-mobile').show();
    $('#socialbtns').removeClass("socialbtns");
    $('#ig').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-instagram");
    $('#twitter').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-twitter");
    $('#linkin').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-linkedin");
    $('#trademark').addClass("footer3");
  }

};
```

```css
/* Base Element Styles */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
}

img {
  height: 250px;
  max-width: 90%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: contain;
}

p {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

a, a:hover, a:link {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: .8;
}

li a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}



/* Containers */
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;

}

.img-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}

.border {
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color:  #121212;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}


/* Base Layout Styles */

.main-header {
  background-image: url("../images/main.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 280px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px  auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.name {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  color: #FFF;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-color: #000;
  border-width: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.services {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #FFF;
}

#nav-mobile {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  top:0;
}
#nav-mobile,
 #nav-mobile ul,
 #nav-mobile li {
  position: relative;
}
#nav-mobile ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav-mobile ul li {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav-mobile a  {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  outline: none;
}

.titles {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.title-button {
  background-color: #121212;
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
}

.main-footer {
 background-color: #121212;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: .9em;
 padding-top: 5px;
 margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-footer ul li {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 90%;
}

.footer3{
  padding-top: 15px;
}

/* Social Media Icons */

.socialbtns li {
  list-style: none outside none;
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.socialbtns .fa {
 width: 40px;
  height: 28px;
 color: #FFF;
 border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -o-border-radius: 20px;
 transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -o-transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

.socialbtns .fa:hover {
 transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
 -o-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
 transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -o-transition: all ease 0.5s;
}




/* Media Queries */
@media only screen and ( min-width: 670px){

  img {
    max-width: 80%;
    height: auto;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }

  .main-header {
    height: 40vh;
  }

  .name {
    font-size: 2.2em;
  }

  .services {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }

  #nav-mobile {
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 630px) and (orientation: landscape) {

  .main-header {
    max-height: 60%;
    height: 100vh;
  }

}

@media only screen and ( min-width: 1000px){

  .container {
    padding: 15px;
  }

  .wrapper {
    height: 90%;
    padding: 0;

  }

  .img-container{
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
  }


  .main-header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .name {
    border-width: 4px;
  }

  .name,
  .services {
    font-size: 3.5em;
  }

  .title {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }


.section1 {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

.section2 {
  width: 40%;
  float: right;
}

.main-footer {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.main-footer ul {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: no-wrap;
}

.main-footer ul li {
  width: 100%;
}

.footer1,
.footer2 {
  width: 45%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: no-wrap;
}

.footer1 {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.footer2,
.footer3 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer2 li:nth-child(1) {
  padding: 0;
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/main.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Menu Icon -->
    <div class="wrapper">
      <nav id="nav-mobile">
          <a >Menu</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="bio.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="photos.html">Photography</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>

    <!-- Home Page -->
      <div class="img-container border">
        <header class ="main-header">
          <div class="title">
            <div class="name"> Luis Rodriguez </div>
            <div class="services"> Web Developer & Photographer </div>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Content Section -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section1">
        <img src="images/pg1.jpg" alt="Photography">
        <div class="titles"> Photography </div>
          <p> In this era a photo does much more than merely remind us of a moment. It has by far become one of the most diverse forms of influence. We capture pictures of loved ones and bring tears of joy years later, while on the other hand busiensses rely on a picture to convey a "million words" to potential clients. Regardless of your story, the right photo should amaze you every time you see it.
          </p>
        <div  class="title-button">
          <a href="photos.html"> My Photos </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section2">
        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="Code">
        <div class="titles"> WebDev </div>
          <p> When you ask someone to browse something online you really never know what they'll use anymore. You can have one person pull out their phone, another use a tablet, you've got someone on a desktop, and there may even be someone using their TV. Having a dynamic website is vital to ensuring that who ever is visiting your site can have a clean simple view to your page regardless of where they see it.
           </p>
        <div class="title-button">
          <a href="code.html">My Code</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <footer class="main-footer">
      <ul>
        <div class="footer1">
          <li><a href="bio.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="footer2">
          <div class="socialbtns" id="socialbtns">
            <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.twitter.com/baesicmedia"  id="twitter" class="fa fa-md fa-twitter"><span id="twitter-text">Twitter</span></a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="#"  id="linkin" class="fa fa-md fa-linkedin"><span> LinkedIn</span></a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/baesicfrs/"  id="ig" class="fa fa-md fa-instagram"><span> Instagram</span></a></li>
          </div>
          <div id="trademark" class="footer3">
            <li>&copy;2017 Baesic Media</li>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </footer>

  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate & clarify what exactly is expected?

Comment: You aren't using any version control for this? Could have helped you.

Comment: Don't put `div` tags into the `ul` in the footer. That's not valid HTML.

Comment: Sorry, they should be linking to other pages, but instead it just toggles versus following the link I have it to redirect to.

Comment: It's my first project I do so definitely appreciate any insight as I probably have basic errors everywhere. Not sure what you mean by version control

Comment: Look at @AbhishekPandey answer, the problem is you're preventing the default action happening when clicking on your anchor tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will help you, your function won't run when `#nav-mobile ul > li >a` has been clicked.

```
$('#nav-mobile').click(function(e) {
   if(!$(e.target).is('#nav-mobile ul > li >a')){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#nav-mobile ul').slideToggle();
   }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#nav-mobile ul').hide();
  $('#socialbtns').removeClass("socialbtns");
  $('#ig').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-instagram");
  $('#twitter').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-twitter");
  $('#linkin').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-linkedin");
  $('#trademark').removeClass("footer3");
  $('#nav-mobile').click(function(e) {
      if(!$(e.target).is('#nav-mobile ul > li >a')){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#nav-mobile ul').slideToggle();
      }
  });
  resize();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    resize();
    if(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 999px)").matches){
      $(' <span> Instagram </span>').appendTo("#ig");
      $(' <span> Twitter </span>').appendTo("#twitter");
      $('<span> LinkedIn </span>').appendTo("#linkin");
      $('#trademark').addClass("footer3");
    }
    });
});


function resize(){
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1000px)").matches) {
    $('#nav-mobile').hide();
    $('#socialbtns').addClass("socialbtns");
    $('#ig').addClass("fa fa-md fa-instagram");
    $('#twitter').addClass("fa fa-md fa-twitter");
    $('#linkin').addClass("fa fa-md fa-linkedin");
    $('span').remove();
    $('#trademark').removeClass("footer3");
  }
  else {
    $('#nav-mobile').show();
    $('#socialbtns').removeClass("socialbtns");
    $('#ig').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-instagram");
    $('#twitter').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-twitter");
    $('#linkin').removeClass("fa fa-md fa-linkedin");
    $('#trademark').addClass("footer3");
  }

};
```

```css
/* Base Element Styles */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
}

img {
  height: 250px;
  max-width: 90%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: contain;
}

p {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

a, a:hover, a:link {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: .8;
}

li a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}



/* Containers */
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;

}

.img-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}

.border {
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color:  #121212;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}


/* Base Layout Styles */

.main-header {
  background-image: url("../images/main.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 280px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px  auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.name {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  color: #FFF;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-color: #000;
  border-width: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.services {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #FFF;
}

#nav-mobile {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  top:0;
}
#nav-mobile,
 #nav-mobile ul,
 #nav-mobile li {
  position: relative;
}
#nav-mobile ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav-mobile ul li {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav-mobile a  {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  outline: none;
}

.titles {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.title-button {
  background-color: #121212;
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
}

.main-footer {
 background-color: #121212;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: .9em;
 padding-top: 5px;
 margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-footer ul li {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 90%;
}

.footer3{
  padding-top: 15px;
}

/* Social Media Icons */

.socialbtns li {
  list-style: none outside none;
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.socialbtns .fa {
 width: 40px;
  height: 28px;
 color: #FFF;
 border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -o-border-radius: 20px;
 transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -o-transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

.socialbtns .fa:hover {
 transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
 -o-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
 transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
 -o-transition: all ease 0.5s;
}




/* Media Queries */
@media only screen and ( min-width: 670px){

  img {
    max-width: 80%;
    height: auto;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }

  .main-header {
    height: 40vh;
  }

  .name {
    font-size: 2.2em;
  }

  .services {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }

  #nav-mobile {
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 630px) and (orientation: landscape) {

  .main-header {
    max-height: 60%;
    height: 100vh;
  }

}

@media only screen and ( min-width: 1000px){

  .container {
    padding: 15px;
  }

  .wrapper {
    height: 90%;
    padding: 0;

  }

  .img-container{
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
  }


  .main-header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .name {
    border-width: 4px;
  }

  .name,
  .services {
    font-size: 3.5em;
  }

  .title {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }


.section1 {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

.section2 {
  width: 40%;
  float: right;
}

.main-footer {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.main-footer ul {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: no-wrap;
}

.main-footer ul li {
  width: 100%;
}

.footer1,
.footer2 {
  width: 45%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: no-wrap;
}

.footer1 {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.footer2,
.footer3 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer2 li:nth-child(1) {
  padding: 0;
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/main.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Menu Icon -->
    <div class="wrapper">
      <nav id="nav-mobile">
          <a >Menu</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="bio.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="photos.html">Photography</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>

    <!-- Home Page -->
      <div class="img-container border">
        <header class ="main-header">
          <div class="title">
            <div class="name"> Luis Rodriguez </div>
            <div class="services"> Web Developer & Photographer </div>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Content Section -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section1">
        <img src="images/pg1.jpg" alt="Photography">
        <div class="titles"> Photography </div>
          <p> In this era a photo does much more than merely remind us of a moment. It has by far become one of the most diverse forms of influence. We capture pictures of loved ones and bring tears of joy years later, while on the other hand busiensses rely on a picture to convey a "million words" to potential clients. Regardless of your story, the right photo should amaze you every time you see it.
          </p>
        <div  class="title-button">
          <a href="photos.html"> My Photos </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section2">
        <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="Code">
        <div class="titles"> WebDev </div>
          <p> When you ask someone to browse something online you really never know what they'll use anymore. You can have one person pull out their phone, another use a tablet, you've got someone on a desktop, and there may even be someone using their TV. Having a dynamic website is vital to ensuring that who ever is visiting your site can have a clean simple view to your page regardless of where they see it.
           </p>
        <div class="title-button">
          <a href="code.html">My Code</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <footer class="main-footer">
      <ul>
        <div class="footer1">
          <li><a href="bio.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="footer2">
          <div class="socialbtns" id="socialbtns">
            <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.twitter.com/baesicmedia"  id="twitter" class="fa fa-md fa-twitter"><span id="twitter-text">Twitter</span></a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="#"  id="linkin" class="fa fa-md fa-linkedin"><span> LinkedIn</span></a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/baesicfrs/"  id="ig" class="fa fa-md fa-instagram"><span> Instagram</span></a></li>
          </div>
          <div id="trademark" class="footer3">
            <li>&copy;2017 Baesic Media</li>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </footer>

  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfect, appreciate the other small corrections too.